# Why does the Java Scheduler exhibit significant time drift on Windows?

Tags: java, time

I have Java service running on Windows 7 that runs once per day on a `SingleThreadScheduledExecutor`. I've never given it much though as it's non critical but recently looked at the numbers and saw that the service was drifting approximately 15 minutes per day which sounds way to much so dug it up.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
   long drift = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeStamp - seconds * 1000);
   lastTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
}, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This method pretty consistently drifts `+110ms` per each 10 seconds. If I run it on a 1 second interval the drift averages `+11ms`.

Interestingly if I do the same on a `Timer()` values are pretty consistent with an average drift less than a full millisecond.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long drift = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimeStamp - seconds * 1000);
        lastTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}, 0, seconds * 1000);
```

**Linux:** doesn't drift (nor with Executor, nor with Timer)
**Windows:** drifts like crazy with Executor, doesn't with Timer

Tested with Java8 and Java11.

Interestingly, if you assume a drift of 11ms per second you'll get 950400ms drift per day which amounts to `15.84 minutes` per day. So it's pretty consistent.

**The question is: why?**
Why would this happen with a SingleThreadExecutor but not with a Timer.

**Update1:** following Slaw's comment I tried on multiple different hardware. What I found is that this issue doesn't manifest on any personal hardware. Only on the company one. On company hardware it also manifests on Win10, though an order of magnitude less.

Comment: Just to note: I don't see a drift on my Windows 10 computer. Running at `1` and `10` second intervals, both for `5` minutes, I got an average drift of `-0.01 ms` and `0.00 ms`, respectively.

Comment: Also note that `Timer#schedule` is equivalent to `ScheduledExecutorService#scheduleWithFixedDelay`, not `scheduleAtFixedRate`.

Comment: As for a difference, it looks like `Timer` uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` while `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` uses `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: @Slaw the nano's vs milis is definitely interesting. I have some new information about the question and will update / close accordingly.

Comment: Time skew on Windows (and Linux) is fairly common. For Linux you only need to install NTP daemon to sync time. For Windows, it depends if machine is part of a domain and how the group policies are setup. With Windows AD, I believe the drift must be less than 5 minutes or authentication breaks. So I guess you are working with a stand alone server that needs a NTP client configured. I think it is already built in (or it used to be), you just need to enable it and point it to the NIST pool.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386048/62576)

Comment: is "Company Hardware" a VPS or is it running on dedicated hardware?

Comment: @hanshenrik dedicated. A beefed up HP Z workstation, Intel Xeon with 24 cores.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` bases its calculations on `System.nanoTime()`. For better or worse, the old `Timer` API however preceeded `nanoTime()`, and so uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` instead.

The difference here might seem subtle, but is more significant than one might expect. Contrary to popular belief, `nanoTime()` is *not* just a "more accurate version" of `currentTimeMillis()`. **Millis is locked to system time, whereas nanos is not.** Or [as the docs put it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()):

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time. [...] **The values returned by this method become meaningful only when the difference between two such values, obtained within the same instance of a Java virtual machine, is computed.**

In your example, you're not following this guidance for the values to be "meaningful" - understandably, because the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` only uses `nanoTime()` as an implementation detail. But the end result is the same, that being that you can't guarantee that it will stay synchronised to the system clock.

But why not? Seconds are seconds, right, so the two should stay in sync from a certain, known point?

Well, in theory, yes. But in practice, probably not.

[Taking a look at the relevant native code on windows](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/os/windows/vm/os_windows.cpp#l833):

```
LARGE_INTEGER current_count;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&current_count);
double current = as_long(current_count);
double freq = performance_frequency;
jlong time = (jlong)((current/freq) * NANOSECS_PER_SEC);
return time;
```

We see `nanos()` uses the `QueryPerformanceCounter` API, which works by `QueryPerformanceCounter` getting the "ticks" of a frequency that's defined by `QueryPerformanceFrequency`. That frequency will stay identical, but the timer it's based off, and its synchronistaion algorithm that windows uses, varies by configuration, OS, and underlying hardware. Even ignoring the above, it's *never* going to be close to 100% accurate (it's based of a reasonably cheap crystal oscillator *somewhere* on the board, not a Caesium time standard!) so it's going to drift out with the system time as NTP keeps it in sync with reality.

In particular, [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps) gives some useful background, and reinforces the above pont:

> When you need time stamps with a resolution of 1 microsecond or better **and you don't need the time stamps to be synchronized to an external time reference**, choose QueryPerformanceCounter.

(Bolding is mine.)

For your specific case of Windows 7 performing badly, note that in Windows 8+, the TSC synchronisation algorithm was improved, and `QueryPerformanceCounter` was *always* based on a TSC (as oppose to Windows 7, where it could be a TSC, HPET or the ACPI PM timer - the latter of which is especially rather inaccurate.) I suspect this is the most likely reason the situation improves tremendously on Windows 10.

That being said, the above factors still mean that you can't rely on the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to keep in time with "real" time - it will always drift. If that drift is an issue, then it's not a solution you can rely on in this context.

*Side note: In Windows 8+, there is a [`GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getsystemtimepreciseasfiletime) which offers the high resolution of `QueryPerformanceCounter` combined with the accuracy of the system time. If Windows 7 was dropped as a supported platform, this could in theory be used to provide a `System.getCurrentTimeNanos()` method or similar, assuming other similar native functions exist for other supported platforms.*

Comment: What an amazing and comprehensive answer. This fits the issue like a glove and perfectly explains the situation. Many thanks!

Comment: @Frankie Glad it was useful! It's always great to see an interesting question like this one too.

Answer (score 3):

[CronScheduler](https://github.com/TimeAndSpaceIO/CronScheduler) is a project of mine designed to be proof against time drift problem, and at the same time it avoids some of the problems with the old `Timer` class [described in this post](https://medium.com/@leventov/cronscheduler-a-reliable-java-scheduler-for-external-interactions-cb7ce4a4f2cd).

Example usage:

```
Duration syncPeriod = Duration.ofMinutes(1);
CronScheduler cron = CronScheduler.create(syncPeriod);
cron.scheduleAtFixedRateSkippingToLatest(0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, runTimeMillis -> {
    // Collect and send summary metrics to a remote monitoring system
});
```

Note: this project was actually inspired by this StackOverflow question.